# What does this { ! } mean in the specific line of code?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I was reading a block of code, which reads an Microsoft access database schema.

Between others i saw that line of code in a loop

```
ColName = SchemaTable.Rows(i)!COLUMN_NAME.ToString
```

Why the exclamation mark is used for { ! }?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN: Special Characters in Code (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxda45fy.aspx)

> **Exclamation Point (!) Operator**
>
> Use the ! operator only on a class or interface as a dictionary access
>   operator. The class or interface must have a default property that
>   accepts a single String argument. The identifier immediately following
>   the ! operator becomes the argument value passed to the default
>   property as a string.
>
> ```
> Public Class hasDefault
>   Default Public ReadOnly Property index(ByVal s As String) As Integer
>     Get
>       Return 32768 + AscW(s)
>     End Get
>   End Property
> End Class
> Public Class testHasDefault
>   Public Sub compareAccess()
>     Dim hD As hasDefault = New hasDefault()
>     MsgBox("Traditional access returns " & hD.index("X") & vbCrLf & 
>       "Default property access returns " & hD("X") & vbCrLf & 
>       "Dictionary access returns " & hD!X)
>   End Sub
> End Class
> ```
>
> The three output lines of MsgBox all display the value 32856. The
>   first line uses the traditional access to property index, the second
>   makes use of the fact that index is the default property of class
>   hasDefault, and the third uses dictionary access to the class.
>
> Note that the second operand of the ! operator must be a valid Visual
>   Basic identifier not enclosed in double quotation marks (" "). In
>   other words, you cannot use a string literal or string variable. The
>   following change to the last line of the MsgBox call generates an
>   error because "X" is an enclosed string literal.
>
> ```
> "Dictionary access returns " & hD!"X")
> ```
>
> References to default collections must be explicit. In particular, you
>   cannot use the ! operator on a late-bound variable.

Answer (score -1):

It's doing a lookup on the collection `SchemaTable`, looking for `COLUMN_NAME.ToString`, then setting that to `ColName`
More information and examples here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129287

Comment: It's not doing that lookup/index on "the collection `SchemaTable`"; it's doing it on `SchemaTable.Rows(i)`. And it's not setting anything to `ColName`: it's setting `ColName` to the result of `.ToString`. Besides, the `!` has nothing to do with that. Finally, your link is dead. Even if those were fixed, this seems like a very vague answer.